# ESLint is not running because the deprecated setting 'eslint.enable' is set to false. Remove the setting and use the extension disablement feature

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

ESLint is not working on my React project, and it keep showing below error even I reinstall vs code(version:1.52.1)

But I have another computer without any problem.

[image]

I was wondering if there are any extensions interfere with each other,

so I removed some extensions and still not working.

Here are the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Open Code > Preferences > Settings

[image]

Search keyword "eslint", and enable "Always show the ESlint status bar item."

[image]

And make sure ESlint is running at bottom right.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that the settings file of the project itself (`.vscode/settings.json`) had the setting `"eslint.enable": false,` in it, for some reason. Removing that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: "For some reason"... Checked the git history, and it was me who added it in there ages ago when we were still using tslint. Oops!